# Can we use to different NS for domain and sub-domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-route53, netlify

I am building an application, for that I am using serverless and netlify. so for the api which is using serverless I want to use sub-domain `api.example.com` and for `dashboard` I want to use `example.com` via netlify,

I purchase the domain via Route53, so that I can use the serverless, but to use netlify I update the domain name server to netlify name server , and I lost the sub-domain in serverless.

Could it be possible to have two different NS for domain and sub-domain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to to have different name servers for domain and subdomain. You have got to understand the resolution process though.

DNS query goes like this .com -> example.com -> api.example.com

As I understood how you have currently configured your DNS:

example.com -> Delegates to Netlify name servers.
Any further subdomains (like api.example.com) will then further be looked into Netlify NS records. If you want to go back to your AWS account again, for that you need to have further delagation for "api.example.com" in your Netlify NS's pointing back again to your hosted zone in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use one provider and then configure the A record and subdomains from the same place?

You can have multiple name servers (for redundancy) but I don't think you want to point a domain and multiple providers. One pointed at GoDaddy and one pointed at Route 53. I'm not sure that would work. Even if it could work, you probably won't want to do that.